# Is there a way that I can use a <select> to order rows in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I have rows that are returned from my database and displayed on the screen:

```
<tr data-ng-repeat="row in grid.data">
```

The rows have columns "id", "number", "text" etc.

Has anyone any examples of how I could create a  drop down that would allow me to select which of these three columns to order the returned rows by?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is actually quite simple, try:

**html**:

```
<body ng-controller="AppCtrl">
  Sort by: <select ng-model="sortField" ng-options="o.label for o in fields"></select>

  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="inverse"> inverse
  </label>

  <hr>

  <table>
    <tr data-ng-repeat="row in grid.data|orderBy:sortField.key:inverse">
      <td>{{row.id}}</td>
      <td>{{row.number}}</td>
      <td>{{row.text}}</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>
```

**js**:

```
app.controller('AppCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.fields = [
    { label: 'ID',   key: 'id' },
    { label: 'Nr.',  key: 'number' },
    { label: 'Text', key: 'text' }
  ];

  $scope.sortField = $scope.fields[2];
  $scope.inverse = false;

  $scope.grid = {
    data: [
      { id: 1, number: 4, text: 'A' },
      { id: 2, number: 3, text: 'E' },
      { id: 3, number: 2, text: 'B' },
      { id: 4, number: 1, text: 'D' },
      { id: 5, number: 0, text: 'C' }
    ]
  };
}]);
```

**demo**: http://jsbin.com/ezadat/1/

Comment: Thanks very much. I like your solution.

Answer (score 1):

First define scope variable for your order direction and access data array via special function:

```
<div ng-app ng-controller="Ctr">
    <select ng-model="orderBy">
        <option>Id</option>
        <option>Name</option>
    </select>

    <ul data-ng-repeat="row in orderData(orderBy)">
        <li>{{row.Id}}: {{row.Name}}</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

The sample controller would look like:

```
function Ctr($scope) {

    // Get your data:
    // (think it can be hidden in context as local variable to not to expose in
    // outside because you'll access the data via special function)
    var data = [
        {Id: 1, Name: 'C'},
        {Id: 2, Name: 'B'},
        {Id: 3, Name: 'A'}
    ];

    // Set default ordering field
    $scope.orderBy = 'Id';

    // Ordering function accessed from UI
    $scope.orderData = function(orderBy) {
        return data.sort(function(a, b) {
            var valueA = a[orderBy];
            var valueB = b[orderBy];
            return (valueA < valueB) ? -1 : (valueA > valueB) ? 1 : 0;
        });
    };
}
```

And order your data in `orderedData` controller's function.

[Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/XyxCZ/1/)

Comment: But would this work if I wanted to change the order on the fly ?

Comment: @Alan, please look at the example I pasted

Comment: and of course it will work because this is the Angularjs was developed for :)